# Do I have to specify cache headers for each page individually?

Tags: .htaccess, caching

This is my code to specify cache expirations:

```
# Expires
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
Header unset Last-Modified
Header set Cache-Control "public"

<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi|html?)$">
Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresActive Off
</FilesMatch>
```

-I'm running APACHE on mediatemple. - Do I have to include an .htaccess file with this code on every directory or is there a way to make it work for the whole site?

Comment: Well usually caching is a good idea for static objects (files and stuff). And for results generated by scripts: it usually is the script that outputs the headers, since the script knows best if the result is worth caching...

Comment: I just want to cache .js, .css and image files. But I haven't been able to do it and I'm using an .htaccess file on each directory with makes it hard to do modifications

Comment: You mean js, css and images were _not_ cached? If that is the case you have a serious issue with your server setup. Fix that instead of trying to work around that issue.